# I want to format a pivot table so if the previous value is greater than 0 (which is formated as background Red), then format Yellow

Tags: formatting, pivot

I want to format a pivot table so if the previous value is greater than 0 (which is formated as background Red), then format Yellow

I want to format a pivot table so if the previous value is greater than 0 (which is formated as background Red), then format Yellow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t471d.png)